# How to clear a growing Exchange 2003 queue

Tags: exchange-2003

Is there a method to clear messages from the queue, other than the manual deletion I am doing now?

Our company sends out mass email notifications to registered users, pulled from a database populated by user entries made on our website. A large number of email entries are bogus or misspelled or have any number of malformed address specifications.

These messages get stuck in the queue, retrying at the predetermined schedule. The list is long. As much fun as this Sisyphean exercise is, I would like to avoid it.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This is a suggestion on how to avoid having to clear the queue.

Whenever you register an e-mail in the database, verify that 1) the address is valid and exists, and 2) the owner of the email address actually submitted his/her own email address willfully. This is sometimes referred to as a ["double opt-in"](http://www.entrepreneurs-journey.com/509/what-is-a-double-opt-in-email-list-and-why-is-it-important/).

This way, you do not only test if the email address is valid and that you can deliver to it, but you also let the user confirm that they actually want your newsletter. If they didn't, **YOU ARE SPAMMING**.

To clear the queue, try this VBScript solution: http://blog.netnerds.net/2006/04/vbscript-delete-all-e-mails-from-the-exchange-2003-queue/

Comment: Thank you for the link to the script. I will keep it as a final option. The opt-in link I will pass to our marketing developers, who handle the campaign. I was hoping there would be a more fine grained feature in Exchange.